# Difference between docker swarm node running as Leader and running as Manager

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, worker, docker-swarm-mode, leader

I wish to understand the difference between docker swarm node running as Leader and running as a Manager.

I also,  understand that there can be several docker managers but can there be multiple docker swarm Leader nodes and the reasons for it.

Note: im aware of what a docker worker node is.

Answer (score 0):

Docker swarm has following terminology.

1. Manager Node (Can be a leader or manager)
2. Worker Node

Now for simple docker swarm mode , there is a single manager and other are worker node. In This manager is a leader.

It is possible to have more then one manager node. Like 2 manager ( Mostly odd number prefer like 1,3,5). In such case to one is leader who is responsible to scheduler task on worker node. Also manager node will talk to each other to maintain the state. To make highly available environment when manager node which is a leader at this moment get down , it should not stop scheduling work. At that moment another manager will automatically promoted as a leader and take responsibility to schedule task (container) on worked node.